# Calculating max of a specific column for a group in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
Postal Code         Risk Category           % of Restaurants

                        Low                         15
   11111                Med                         60
                        High                        25

                        Low                         30
   22222                Med                         20
                        High                        50
```

I have 2 questions

1. how do I return the postal code with the highest % of high risk category restaurants (in this case, it would return postal code 2222 as it has 50% high risk category restaurants)
2. Is there a way i can create a new column labeled '% High Risk' that shows the number of high risk restaurants for each postal code (would be useful for visualization purposes) This would look something like this:

```
Postal Code         Risk Category           % of Restaurants.      %High Risk
    
                        Low                         15
   11111                Med                         60                 25
                        High                        25
    
                        Low                         30
   22222                Med                         20                 50
                        High                        50
```

Comment: `df['% High Risk'] = df[df['Risk Category'] == 'High']['% of Restaurants']`This allows for conditional extraction, but does it meet the intent of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Group by `Postal Code` and get the `% of Restaurants` where `Risk Category` is 'High'. Then merge the resulting dataframe on `Postel Code`

```
df.merge(
    df.groupby('Postal Code')
        .apply(lambda x: x['% of Restaurants'][x['Risk Category'].eq('High')]).rename('% High Risk')
    , on='Postal Code')
```

Out:

```
   Postal Code Risk Category  % of Restaurants  % High Risk
0        11111           Low                15           25
1        11111           Med                60           25
2        11111          High                25           25
3        22222           Low                30           50
4        22222           Med                20           50
5        22222          High                50           50
```

---

### For absolute counts

If `% of Restaurants` were `#(Number) of Restaurants` it could be done similarly

```
df.merge(
    df.groupby('Postal Code')
        .apply(lambda x: x[x['Risk Category'].eq('High')]['% of Restaurants']/x['% of Restaurants'].sum() * 100).rename('% High Risk')
    , on='Postal Code')
```

Out:

```
   Postal Code Risk Category  # of Restaurants  % High Risk
0        11111           Low                15         25.0
1        11111           Med                60         25.0
2        11111          High                25         25.0
3        22222           Low                30         50.0
4        22222           Med                20         50.0
5        22222          High                50         50.0
```